# Sigil EPUB: Auto-generating internal links to illustrations

Tags: epub, sigil

I'm working on converting a large book from its original digital masters to EPUB. I'm using Sigil right now, but am open to using other tools where appropriate.

This book contains a lot (240!) of numbered and labeled illustrations, and the text of the book references back to the illustrations using "figure 000" where "000" is the number.

Some figures will be on their own pages/sections of the book; others will be inline with paragraphs of text.

Is there a way for Sigil to find all references to figures and the illustrations themselves, and generate links? Something that uses regex would be fine.